# Is it possible to change the colour of PanedWindow sash - Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

its just white by default, is there a property that changes the colour of the sash bar (not the handle)

```
tkinter.PanedWindow(root, orient = "vertical", width = 600, sashwidth = 5, [sashcolor = "#222222"?])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out a method, changing the background to the desired colour and setting the border width to 0 so the background is only visible though the sash

```
tkinter.PanedWindow(root, orient = "vertical", width = 600, sashwidth = 5, bg = "#FF0000", bd = 0)
```